# HAML: Create data-xxx-yyy attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, haml

I know how to create a link with a data-* attribute:

```
%a{ :href => "#", :data => { :name ="John", :age => 24 } } Hi John
```

generates:

```
<a href="#" data-name="John" data-age="24">Hi John</a>
```

But how about a 2 deep data name, like `data-user-name` and `data-user-age`, a way to group data attributes. As you may guess, I tried:

```
:data => { :user => { :name => "John", :age => 24 } }
```

But it doesn't work, giving me strange HTML output:

```
<a href="#" data-user="nameJohnage24">Hi John</a>
```

Any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll have to use

```
:data => {'user-name' => 'John', 'user-age' => 24}
```

The `data` attribute is special-cased by HAML and it only accounts for shallow values.

Comment: So, it's not possible to group `user-` the way we grouped `data-`?

Comment: No, because the `data` attribute is special-cased by HAML and it only accounts for shallow values. You could open an issue at https://github.com/haml/haml to spark some discussion on it. I didn't look but I wouldn't be surprised if it had been mentioned before.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can! From the simple...

```
%a(data-user-name="John", data-user-last-name="Arbuckle")
```

To the complex

```
%a(data-user-name="#{User.first.name}", data-stack-overflow="all of these will be custom attributes in your link"){href: "garfield.com"}
```